# prepared statement without values and before html output

Tags: php, pdo

```
$sql = "select col1, col2, col3 from t1 order by date desc limit 500"
```

There is no place for binding anything, so do I need (and how) to make a prepared statement?

Another example:

```
$sql = "select col1 from t1  where col1 = 'val1' order by date desc"
```

If this code is placed **before** html output (while loading the page, without any user input values), do I need the prepared statement?

I suppose sql injection is not possible if there is no yet any interaction with users.

Comment: You only need to prepare your statements if the query includes user input - you needn't use it if the SQL is hard-coded

Comment: If there is no user input, then no, you do not need to use prepared statements. The second statement would only benefit it so that you do not need to worry about quoting.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need prepared statements if the query isn't expecting user supplied arguments.